# matrix divided by rows of another matrix, without a loop in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, division

What is the equivalent numpy implementation of the code below without using a loop?

```
dt = np.dtype(np.float32)

a=[[12,3],
   [2,4],
   [2,4],]

b=[[12,3,2,3],
   [2,4,4,5]]

a=np.asarray(a,dtype=dt)
b=np.asarray(b,dtype=dt)
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
ainvb=np.zeros((3,2,4))
for i in range(4):
   ainvb[:,:,i]=a/b[:,i].T
```

What I need to do is to divide columns of "a" by each row of "b". At the end, there will 4 matrices of size 3*2 (size of "a") where each are "a" divided by one of the rows of "b".

Is it possible to do it without a loop in numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a numpy solution, make use of array broadcasting by inserting singleton dimensions in your arrays:

```
 ainvb2=a[:,:,None]/b[None,:,:]
```

This works by transforming `a` to shape `(3,2,1)` and `b` to shape `(1,2,4)`. They can then be broadcast together, and the singleton dimensions will do exactly what you need.

Or as [TheBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604159/theblackcat) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068204/matrix-divided-by-rows-of-another-matrix-without-a-loop-in-numpy-and-theano/34068635#comment55890368_34068635), you can access "all remaining dimensions" of `a` using `...`, and leading singleton dimensions are also implicitly assumed during broadcast, so you can simply use

```
ainvb2=a[...,None]/b
```

Comparison with your looping solution:

```
In [530]: (ainvb==ainvb2).all()
Out[530]: True
```

Comment: You don't need the `None` in `b`, and you can use `...` in `a` to mean "all existing dimensions", so this will work: `a[..., None]/b`

Comment: @TheBlackCat thank you! I didn't know about `...` (still in the early stage of learning python), and coming from matlab I only tried to omit the *trailing* singletons in `a` (as opposed to the leading singletons in `b`) :)

Comment: @Anxam alas, I don't know anything about theano. But I guess you already suspected that, having removed the theano tag:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I decided to start a new question about theano and updated this question, also selected your answer.

Comment: @Anxam I believe that's your best option. And thank you:)